# Websphere 7 SIB Queue: how to access queue depth from Java?

Tags: java, websphere, mq

I've created some code to access queue depths for a Websphere MQ, but I can't work out if there is an API for accessing a SIB queue, or if I can setup websphere to allow me to access it.

Can anyone give me some hints/ideas?

Thanks
Jeff Porter

Comment: possible duplicate of [Websphere 7 SIB Queue: how to access queue depth wsadmin command?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8153032/websphere-7-sib-queue-how-to-access-queue-depth-wsadmin-command)

Comment: nope, not a duplicate. The first question was about getting the details from command line wsadmin command, this question is about doing the same thing but from Java code (via an api call)

Comment: @JeffPorter - I answered your question from a non WASADMIN perspective in your previous question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7759113/websphere-7-mqueue-how-to-access-queue-depth-from-java/7767912#7767912. Also you may want to quit naming your questions the same. If you didn't get the answer you desired, please put a bounty on the question or tell people in comments that you aren't getting what you are looking for.

Comment: OK, I see. Unfortunately, no option to rescind a close vote.  However given your comment here, probably no additional close votes will be received.  Wish I knew more about WAS to answer this.

Answer (score 1):

The answer, for those that care is SOAP.

Ok, so I've not managed to get the API used by WSADMIN to work, but I've used SOAP direct into websphere to ask it about the queues.

Note: Default port is 8880

```
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.TreeMap;

import javax.management.ObjectName;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

import com.ibm.websphere.management.AdminClient;
import com.ibm.websphere.management.AdminClientFactory;

 <SNIP>
 Properties connectProps = new Properties();
 connectProps.setProperty(AdminClient.CONNECTOR_TYPE, AdminClient.CONNECTOR_TYPE_SOAP);
 connectProps.setProperty(AdminClient.CONNECTOR_HOST, "127.0.0.1");
 connectProps.setProperty(AdminClient.CONNECTOR_PORT, "8880"); 

 AdminClient adminClient = null;
    try
    {
      adminClient = AdminClientFactory.createAdminClient(connectProps);

      Set<ObjectName> s2 = adminClient.queryNames(new ObjectName("WebSphere:*"), null);
      if (!s2.isEmpty())
      {
        Iterator<ObjectName> i = s2.iterator();
        while (i.hasNext())
        {
          ObjectName on = i.next();
          String type = on.getKeyProperty("type");
          if ("SIBQueuePoint".equals(type))
          {
            String queueName = on.getKeyProperty("name") ;
            int currentDepth =  ((Integer) adminClient.getAttribute(on, "depth")).intValue();
            int maxSize =  ((Integer) adminClient.getAttribute(on, "highMessageThreshold")).intValue();

            LOG.info("Queried SIB queue: Queue: [" + queueName + "] Size =[" + currentDepth + "] highMessageThreshold:["+maxSize+"]");
          }
        }
      }
      else {
        System.out.println("MBean was not found");
      }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
      LOG.error("Error finding SIB queue details, message:" + e.getMessage(), e); 
    }
```