# Check MQ queue depth

Tags: java, ibm-mq

Can anyone help in doing the code in java of getting the depth of the queues. We are having 4 queues in IBM WebSphere MQ and inside them there are messages.

I want to write a jsp to read the queue names and their depth while running the report.
How do I do that?

Answer (score 4):

See http://blog.guymahieu.com/2008/06/11/getting-the-depth-of-an-mqseries-queue-from-java/.

I re-implemented this as follows:

```
import com.ibm.mq.*;

public class QueueManager {

    private final String host;
    private final int port;
    private final String channel;
    private final String manager;
    private final MQQueueManager qmgr;

    public QueueManager(String host, int port, String channel, String manager) throws MQException {
        this.host = host;
        this.port = port;
        this.channel = channel;
        this.manager = manager;
        this.qmgr = createQueueManager();
    }

    public int depthOf(String queueName) throws MQException {
        MQQueue queue = qmgr.accessQueue(queueName, MQC.MQOO_INQUIRE | MQC.MQOO_INPUT_AS_Q_DEF, null, null, null);
        return queue.getCurrentDepth();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private MQQueueManager createQueueManager() throws MQException {
        MQEnvironment.channel = channel;
        MQEnvironment.port = port;
        MQEnvironment.hostname = host;
        MQEnvironment.properties.put(MQC.TRANSPORT_PROPERTY, MQC.TRANSPORT_MQSERIES);
        return new MQQueueManager(manager);
    }
}
```

Put the following jars on your classpath:

- com.ibm.mq*jar
- j2ee.jar

Comment: The specific jars to put in the path is unsupported and version-specific. Prior to V8 IBM required a full client install if you wanted support for your client.  As of v8.0 IBM has a jar-only supported client configuration but that isn't the right list of jars for it.

Comment: This helped, I just needed to change transport mode to binding.

Answer (score 0):

I saw a response [access queue with Websphere MQ API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7759113/websphere-7-mqueue-how-to-access-queue-depth-from-java/7767912#7767912)

Have you look at MBeans accessibles in JMX context ? If I had to do that I'll expose it in a Mbean.

You can see there [IBM JMS Topologies](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/dw/wes/pdf/jmstopologies.pdf)

> For monitoring and checking the status of resources, such as queue depths, there are a couple of options. The preferred option is to use the JMX Mbeans provided with Application Serve for monitoring: JMSBasicFunction, JMSAdministration, and EmbeddedJMSAdministration.
>   You can access these Mbeans through wsadmin or programmatically. Secondly, you can use the traditional WMQ administration utilities, such as runmqsc or MQExplorer, to look at queues and other resources. If you do use these utilities, it is essential that you do not make any configuration changes to the Application Server queue manager and queues. These resources are under the control of Application Server. Making changes to these resources using the MQ utilities results in a non-functioning configuration

Dont know if you are on a WAS server and if this is still the same MBeans, but you should find equivalents Mbeans on your AS.