# find the queue depth of MQ

Tags: java, jms, mq

I want to find the current queue depth of MQ. My program can read and write on queue.

I am able to write a consumer to consume message from queue. I can use counter to count how many messages were in queue. But I need to find the queue depth without loosing the messages.

```
try {
        // Create a connection factory
        JmsFactoryFactory ff = JmsFactoryFactory.getInstance(WMQConstants.WMQ_PROVIDER);
        JmsConnectionFactory cf = ff.createConnectionFactory();

        // Set the properties
        cf.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_HOST_NAME, HOST);
        cf.setIntProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_PORT, PORT);
        cf.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_CHANNEL, CHANNEL);
        cf.setIntProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_CONNECTION_MODE, WMQConstants.WMQ_CM_CLIENT);
        cf.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_QUEUE_MANAGER, QMGR);
        cf.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_APPLICATIONNAME, "JmsPutGet (JMS)");
        cf.setBooleanProperty(WMQConstants.USER_AUTHENTICATION_MQCSP, true);
        cf.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.USERID, APP_USER);
        cf.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.PASSWORD, APP_PASSWORD);

        // Create JMS objects
        context = cf.createContext();
        destination = context.createQueue("queue:///" + QUEUE_NAME);

        long uniqueNumber = System.currentTimeMillis() % 1000;
        TextMessage message = context.createTextMessage("Your lucky number today is " + uniqueNumber);

        producer = context.createProducer();
        producer.send(destination, message);
        System.out.println("Sent message:\n" + message);

        consumer = context.createConsumer(destination); // autoclosable
        String receivedMessage = consumer.receiveBody(String.class, 15000); // in ms or 15 seconds

        System.out.println("\nReceived message:\n" + receivedMessage);

        recordSuccess();
    }
```

The code should print the queue depth.

Comment: It seems you question is already answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8660991/get-queues-depth-from-java-code

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: This is just for learning. I want to see how many messages are there in MQ server.

Comment: Another way to get the queue depth is to use a JMS Browser and count msgs. However, getting the queue depth is no a usual task for an application. If your app is the only one on this queue, why not immediately read all messages ? you will need them anyway. If there are other apps on this queue, the number might be wrong once you got it (the other apps might have added/deleted messages in the meantime)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Queue depth can be counted by browsing messages. Browsing does not consume messages.

```
Connection connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();
connection.start();

Session session = connection.createSession(false, Session.DUPS_OK_ACKNOWLEDGE);
Queue q = session.createQueue("exampe_queue");
QueueBrowser browser = session.createBrowser(q);
Enumeration enumeration = browser.getEnumeration();

long msgCounter = 0;
while (enumeration.hasMoreElements()) {
    Message msg = (Message) enumeration.nextElement();
    msgCounter += 1;
}

System.out.println("Queue depth: " + msgCounter);
```

However this method is very **slow** as client is pulling messages from broker. It will work if you need to check your queue depth sporadically for monitoring purpose or similar.

Better solution would be to use get-me-a-q-depth call but this is not specified by JMS api; however it is usually present in the implementation specific library.

Comment: This could be very expensive.  If you have 100,000 messages on the a queue - this is a lot of traffic, and a lot of work for the backend.  For monitoring it would be better to have another process which queries the curdepth periodically and takes action.  Or have queue high event.