# how to check the size of the messages in a queue in IBM MQ while writing an asynchronous process

Tags: java, ibm-mq

I had written an asynchronous process to subscribe messages from IBM MQ  queue but unable to find any method to know the size of an queue

```
    Queue queue;
    QueueSession session;
    QueueReceiver receiver;
    QueueConnection con;
            con=factory.createQueueConnection("user1"," password1");
            queue= new MQQueue("myQueue");
            session=con.createQueueSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
            receiver=session.createReceiver(queue);
            receiver.setMessageListener(this);
            con.start();
```

the above is the functonality i am using , in this receiver attribute is not showing any size or length methods tro check number of messages there

Comment: Do you mean the depth of a queue ?

Comment: Answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57862719/find-the-queue-depth-of-mq. Any reason for doing so? In my opinion, your application should consume messages as long as it is running.

Comment: Yes kaustubh.. i need depth of the queue but it would change dynamically as publishers would publish messages on daily basis

Comment: Browsing the queue could be very expensive.  Consider 100,000 messages on the queue. If this was a client, there would be a lot of network traffic, and high CPU cost at the backend.  For monitoring consider another task which issues display queue depth.  If queue builds up you could start more application instances.