# JMS API cannot browse messages, IBM API can

Tags: java, jms, ibm-mq

My current application logic uses the depth of the a 'PROCESS' WMQ queue to determine if a job is being processed by an IIB9 workflow. If the workflow is processing a messages, the application wait till that workflow is over. Once the workflow is over, the 'PROCESS' queue will be emptied using GET operation and the application sends other messages in the sequence for processing. I am using JMS selectors to differentiate between multiple messages being processed parallelly by the workflow.

The issue is with determining the depth of the queue. JMS API is giving the depth as 0, while IBM API is giving the depth as 1(which is expected). Unfortunately, I cannot use IBM API as my logic using some complex messageselectors.

Has anyone seen this bizarre behaviour? Please note that the IIB9 workflow is in progress while the size check is being made. Is there a setting to be tweaked?

JMS Code (message selector removed for clarity):

```
public class QDepthJMS {

public static void main(String[] a) throws Exception {
    MQConnectionFactory factory = new MQConnectionFactory();
    factory.setTransportType(WMQConstants.WMQ_CM_CLIENT);
    factory.setQueueManager("QM01");
    factory.setHostName("10.10.98.15");
    factory.setPort(1414);
    factory.setChannel("Java.Clients");

    MQConnection connection = (MQConnection) factory.createConnection();
    connection.start();

    MQSession session = (MQSession) connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);

    MQQueue queue = (MQQueue) session.createQueue("queue:///PROCESS");
    MQQueueBrowser browser = (MQQueueBrowser) session.createBrowser(queue); 

    Enumeration<Message> msgs = browser.getEnumeration();
    int count =0;
    if (msgs.hasMoreElements()) {
        msgs.nextElement();
        ++count;
    }

    System.out.println(count);
}
}
```

IBM API ([Check MQ queue depth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8656245/check-mq-queue-depth)):

```
public class QDepth {

private final String host;
private final int port;
private final String channel;
private final String manager;
private final MQQueueManager qmgr;

public QDepth(String host, int port, String channel, String manager) throws MQException {
    this.host = host;
    this.port = port;
    this.channel = channel;
    this.manager = manager;
    this.qmgr = createQueueManager();
}

public int depthOf(String queueName) throws MQException {
    MQQueue queue = qmgr.accessQueue(queueName, MQC.MQOO_INQUIRE | MQC.MQOO_INPUT_AS_Q_DEF, null, null, null);
    return queue.getCurrentDepth();
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
private MQQueueManager createQueueManager() throws MQException {
    MQEnvironment.channel = channel;
    MQEnvironment.port = port;
    MQEnvironment.hostname = host;
    MQEnvironment.properties.put(MQC.TRANSPORT_PROPERTY, MQC.TRANSPORT_MQSERIES);
    return new MQQueueManager(manager);
}

public static void main(String[] a) throws Exception {
    QDepth qd = new QDepth("10.10.98.15, 1414, "Java.Clients", "QM01");
    System.out.println(qd.depthOf("PROCESS"));
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not comparing "like with like" - The IBM API queries the queue depth, ie how many messages are in the queue but the JMS API is browsing through the messages and counting them. There is a valid reason for them to be different - the usual cause is that someone has put a message under a unit of work (syncpoint) and it has not yet been committed - Therefore at the point you run the IBM API it will say there's 1 message on the queue (there is...) but it is not gettable / browseable as its not yet committed.

You can verify this using runmqsc (and probably the GUI) by runmqsc DIS QSTATUS and look at the UNCOM attribute - See http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21636775

Comment: Adding to Jason's reply: JMS 1.1 specification does not describe any API for determining the queue depth. So it's not bizarre.

Comment: @JasonE, Your suggestion indeed fixed the problem. I was in a transaction(UOW) context and hence the message was unavailable to browse. I have disabled Transaction Mode on the IIB9 Workflow and the issue is fixed.